# Аналог функции empty

Tags: pascal

Есть ли в Pascal аналог функции empty в php, чтобы проверить строку, есть ли там данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if length(string) = 0 then ...
```

Comment: ПОжалуйста, примите ответ, если он Вам помог. http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading10